# UILabel Attributed Text doesn't fill entire line before starting a new line

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift4, nsattributedstring

As you can see from the image, the background of the `UILabel` is set to yellow. The attributed text does not use all the space before wrapping to the next line ("at" should be in the first line). Any way to fix it?

[image]

The label is constructed as follows. It is inside a `UICollectionView` header, and positioned by autolayout

```
let astring = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "You asked friends, and people at ")
astring.append(NSAttributedString(string:"Pittsburgh", 
    attributes: [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]))

let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = astring
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in iOS 11 as per the following link -

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89145

I tested on iOS 9 and iOS 11. It works fine in iOS 9. I do not have iOS 10 simulator, however, as per the above link comments, it works in iOS 10 as well. It doesn't work on iOS 11. Frankly, I do not have any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, odd bug...

One work-around, although I haven't done any testing on it except to see that it works in your case.

Append a "no-width space" character at the end:

```
    let astring = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "You asked friends, and people at ")
    astring.append(NSAttributedString(string:"Pittsburgh",
                                      attributes: [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]))
    astring.append(NSAttributedString(string:"\u{200b}",
                                      attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, it works. Wonder why. But thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Append the ""\u{200b}" in Attributed String in End . hope it it will work ,